# Trying to get data to the recycler view after clicking a button present above the recycler view

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

if i have a page where buttons lies on the top and below a recyclerview.I want to get something in that recyler view on clicking the above button.
How to get it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: post your full code

Comment: Please clarify your problem.